# Is this the best solution to move social icons to the right side of the page?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to move the social icons to the right side at the top of the page, and reverse their order in my WordPress theme, using CSS only and not HTML.

Here's my page http://qattaj.com. And this is the workaround I want to do with the css file:

```
 #ishyoboy-social-widget-5
    {
    width: 100%;
    }
    .onepcssgrid-1200
    {
    width: 100% !important;
    }
    .header-widgets
    {
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
    }
    .social
    {
    width: 100% !important;
    }
```

I tried it and it works, but do you think this is the best "CSS" approach?

Editing the html will make me lose all modifications once I update the theme to a future version. I'm using a child theme with its CSS to keep my modifications even if the theme is updated in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give widget Full width

```
div#ishyoboy-social-widget-5 {
width: 100%;
}
```

Float the social icons to right in reverse order

```
.header-widgets ul.social li {
float: right;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use this css :

```
.col6 {
    width: 100%;
}
.header-widgets ul.social {
    float: right;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```